# Java unable to read files with some "special" characters

Tags: java, linux

I wrote a java program to print the length of files in Java

```
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.nio.charset.Charset;
  import java.nio.file.Files;

  public class FTPTest {
          public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
                  File dirFile = new File("/home/chandakv/Desktop/test/vishal");
                  File[] ab = dirFile.listFiles();
                  for (int i = 0; i < ab.length; i++) {
                          System.out.println(ab[i].getName() + "\t" + ab[i].length());
                  }
          }
  }
```

It works fine with normal files but with one file having the file name:

**bjliretimessitb_u.'192.168.200.38' ?Ïµ? ?Ú²????? (Y).lnk**

It is unable to read that file. If I am renaming that file (even removing any valid characters) it is working as expected. Till now, I am able to figure out that **.lnk** is not the problem and when renaming the file, the Linux explorer converts the encoding to ASCII so the file is being processed.

But, how to process the file normally without modifying its name.

FYI, on running the above program,

```
file.isFile() -> Returns false
file.isReadable() -> Returns false
file.length() -> Returns 0
```

And on linux "ls -l" shows file size as 207 bytes.

Comment: .lnk? Is the file a Windows shortcut on a Samba share?

Comment: a .lnk file is usually associated with windows. so how are you getting these .lnk files ?

Comment: LNK is a file extension for a shortcut file used by Windows to point to an exe.

Comment: What exactly is the undesired behavior? An exception? A value other than 207?

Comment: Since he's able to read the file and it works as expected if he removes the unexpected characters from the filename I think the problem is not in the .lnk extension. It is probably in the encoding of filename.

Comment: I think something is mangling the Unicode encoding of the filename. I would make a short filename that starts with a Unicode character that requires 4 bytes in UTF-16, then look at the numeric values of the characters Java thinks the filename contains.

Comment: For example, U+20000 is &#131072;, which encodes as 0xD840 0xDC00 in UTF-16 and 0xF0 0xA0 0x80 0x80 in UTF-8.

Comment: it is unclear what you are saying: in  System.out.println(ab[i].getName()) does it print out the name?

Comment: @gpasch yes it does print out the name but just question marks in place of unsupported characters.

Comment: @DiogoRocha yes you are correct, the problem is not even in those special characters but how they are encoded is the problem

Comment: @JohnSensebe I tried using UTF-16 file encoding in Eclipse if that is what you are saying but it didn't help.....it may be possible that I might have used UTF-16 in the wrong way

Comment: @TomBlodget the value returned is 0 where as correct value is 207

Comment: If it is printing question marks, I would look at the numeric values of the characters and find out if they are coming in as question marks. The ASCII/Unicode value for the question mark is 0x3F or 63 in decimal. Alternatively, you can search the string for the question mark character and print a warning if one is found.

Comment: I think if `isFile()` returns false, `length()` will return 0, meaning "not applicable."

Comment: What gets printed to the console or in a debugger window is entirely a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should write file name character as unicode encoded \uxxxx

in your code all unicode characters converted to question mark then the file does not exists

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new `PrintStream` (don't use the default `System.out` `PrintStream`) using UTF8 encoding.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
out.println(unicodeText);
```

Your code would look like this:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

File dirFile = new File("/home/chandakv/Desktop/test/vishal");
File[] ab = dirFile.listFiles();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
for (int i = 0; i < ab.length; i++) {
    out.println(ab[i].getName() + "\t" + ab[i].length());
}
```